# Exception to the order reaction and stoichiometric coefficient equality in elementary reactions

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

When a reaction is elementary,the stoichiometric coefficients **always** equal the order for each reactant? Is there any exception? Because at Ángel González Ureña's *Cinética Química* it says that this is "in general cases", but not always. I haven't found any results in google about this topic.

Comment: Elementary reactions always involve a single molecule reacting (e.g. isomerisation)  or two colliding and so react. So no exceptions. (Some texts include three molecules colliding but the chance of this is so small it never happens in practice. It is found experimentally  that an intermediate is formed, so it is a two step process.)

Comment: If the order is not equal to the stoichiometric coefficient, the reaction is not elementary.

Comment: Yes, like @Maurice, I thought this is the defining property. I guess you could have a multi-step reaction where the orders happen to be equal to the stoichiometric coefficients, so I guess the definition has to be more than that.